# Generate a poster image from Spring

Tags: spring-mvc, dynamic-image-generation

I want to create a Spring view that will take an object from the request, and generate a .png poster based on that object. Is there an existing View technology for that?

Comment: what kind of object do you mean? Like JSON? I mean, you can generate an image based on whatever you want. Drawing: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html

Comment: If you mean the other way around, drawing on client side, then HTML5 has the canvas element: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/canvas_drawing.asp

Comment: no i mean drawing on the server side to generate a .png

Comment: you need to specify more detailed what you want to do. what kind of object will you pass to the server? what data will it contain?

Comment: what does it matter? Any object, the point is that my view will process the object and generate an image. I don't need you to do this for me, just to point in the right direction. Currently I am looking at Apache PDFBox.